# Solr not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I tried to manually run solr its works

But when i try to run it via sunspot rails gem

its gives this error

Solr not working on fresh installations

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

```
Severe errors in solr configuration.
```

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

false

in solr.xml

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'lang/stopwords_en.txt' in classpath or '/home/mirraw-dev/projects/mirraw-dev/solr/./conf/', cwd=/home/mirraw-dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@mirraw-dev/gems/sunspot_solr-1.3.3/solr
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getLines(SolrResourceLoader.java:318)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getLines(SolrResourceLoader.java:292)
    at org.apache.solr.analysis.BaseTokenStreamFactory.getWordSet(BaseTokenStreamFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory.inform(StopFilterFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:551)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:478)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:332)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)

Powered by Jetty://
```

Content of stopwords

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
```

Comment: well, is there a `lang/stopwords_en.txt` somewhere?

Comment: yes. posted it inside the question

Comment: it's inside conf directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a lang/stopwords_en.txt file. It is part of solr codebase. and your error has the path where it should be located. On my local if see something like below:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# a couple of test stopwords to test that the words are really being
# configured from this file:
stopworda
stopwordb

# Standard english stop words taken from Lucene's StopAnalyzer
a
an
and
are
as
at
be
but
by
for
if
in
into
is
it
no
not
of
on
or
such
that
the
their
then
there
these
they
this
to
was
will
with
```